# Event custom fields not carried over to repeat events

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

When we set up a recurring event, data in custom event fields isn't carried over to the repeated events. Similarly, if a recurring event is edited and we tell it to overwrite all the occurrences, only the edited event will retain the custom data.

(This is in v4.6.4, but I'm able to duplicate this in the online demo)

Answer (score 2):

This sure seems like an oversight on CiviCRM's part.  Good call for testing on the demo to rule out some weird problem on your site.

At this point, the bug needs to be reported and fixed.  Go to [issues.civicrm.org](http://issues.civicrm.org) and create an issue.  That way it can be triaged and assigned to the best person to fix it.

Unfortunately, until a fix comes out, you'll have to manually select the new recurring events in the custom data settings.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add an issue (the issue tracker seems to be down at the mo', but I'll get back to it later).

Comment: Right, I've added it as a bug here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16902 (This is exciting, I've never reported a bug before. Usually it's something I've screwed up :)